# is there any script which can stop to show ALT="text" as a tooltip in IE 6 and 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mootools

is there any script which can stop to show ALT="text" as a tooltip in IE 6 and 7?

Comment: I don't get - why would you have alt text and try to not show it??

Comment: Because that's not what alt text is for.. That's what title is for.

Comment: Tell this to M$ :) But still - ALT is "short" for alternative text.

Comment: @Jeffrey Aylesworth yes u r right

Comment: @Trick - yes ALT is "short" for alternative text but for screen reader not sighted user

Comment: Of course... I didn't think in that way...

Comment: Incredible: IE8 does not have this bug anymore, cool it took just 10 years at IE developer team to finally understand this was a bug and to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--[if IE]><script>for(i =0;i<document.images.length;i++){document.images[i].alt='';}</script><![endif]-->
```

at the end of the page should do it.

Comment: "To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this file from showing active content that could access your computer. Click here for options"

Comment: @Jitendra I guess you are running it on local machine. Read more about the warning message at http://www.psychpage.com/tech/damnbar.html

Comment: @VSR - will this script slow down page rendering?

Comment: This will remove the alternative text from any screen reader running over IE (so it is a really bad idea)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't worry too much about it. [It's a known bug and it's fixed in IE8.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288472(VS.85).aspx#access)

Comment: if i add title and alt both on a image then what will be show on mouseover?

Comment: title​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.

Comment: @Kemper: Sad, but true. Still, considering the work involved to make a page IE6-compatible, I think it's OK if a site looks "a little bit less nice" in IE6, as long as its main functionality works.

Comment: Would be sad, but not true. IE6 is certainly not the most used browser anymore, not even during the weekday daytime hours.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('img').each(function (i, el) {
  if (!el.hasAttribute('title')) {
    el.setAttribute('title', '');
  }
});
```

That should give all images without a `title` attribute an empty one. I'm not sure if it will fix the problem for IE6 and IE7 but I think they support `title` and this might override it.

Answer (score 2):

In IE before IE8 the only way to avoid the browser to show images alt text as tooltip are:

1. not to use the alt attribute (which is not a good idea because it's not valid HTML and it's not good even for Google SEO and text readers that can not see your images).
2. place in each image a `title=""` empty attribute.

In order to accomplish point (2) using a simple Javascript with no jQuery, you have to place this small piece of code before ending BODY tag, like this:

```
   <!--[if lt IE 8]>
      <script>
         for(var i = 0, imgs = document.images, len = imgs.length; i < len; ++i)
            if(!imgs[i].title)
               imgs[i].title = "";
      </script>
   <![endif]-->            
</body>
```

You can write it in one line if you prefer.

The advantaghe of this code is that it does not screw up the alt tag attributes of your images, it simply sets the title attribute to empty string, unless a title attribute is already defined in this last case I suppose the title attribute was defined because you want to show whatever you wrote in title attribute as a tooltip (which is a cross-browser behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

```
$$('img').set('alt', '');
```

No other way, apart from setting the **title** attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following but it would be very intrusive (and a bit slow):

```
$('*').attr('alt', '');
```

Comment: This doesn't remove it from the source code, but from the DOM which is in memory. Bots will not be affected, and you could couple this with a jQuery.support call in order to execute it only on IE6 and IE7

Comment: Sidenote: This is jQuery notation.

Comment: @Boldewyn: yes it is but I saw the jQuery tag so I thought that the author uses jQuery anyway

Comment: Really, it'd be more appropriate to target just the images $('img') instead of all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably for `alt` attribute, you just mean image elements?

```
$('img').removeAttr('alt');
```

You may also consider removing the `title` attribute from elements in the DOM

```
$('*').removeAttr('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do screan reader run javascript? If not then why bother with this mod?

Setting alt to "" would hide the alt "tooltip" in IE < 8 which seems to be all you are after. Plus this should be done anyway for all image or else screen readers have a habit of of rendering out a default "image placeholder" speech. If you set it to blank then it won't bother and will skip it, ideal for images that are simply used for design rather than content.

Unfortunately there is no special flag or switch you can flick via JS or any other method to tell IE to behave any differently in this regard which is what I believe you are asking for.

An alternative is to switch any alts you find in images to be titles but this does not get rid of the tooltips, you just end up making them appear in all browsers then rather than just IE.

So the final fix is to simply clear all alt attributes in images (and there are scripts in other answers here that do just that). You asked the question but I think you should ponder about what it is you are trying to achieve and more importantly, why and is it that essential?